# Transit points to the Bahamas other than in the USA

Tags: usa, transit, bahamas, gambian-citizens

I want to travel to the Bahamas, but I do not want to transit the USA. Are there any possible transit points for Gambian nationals en route to the Bahamas which do not go through the USA?

Comment: It is possible to get a USA transit visa, even if you have been previously refused a tourist visa.

Comment: For some people it is a case not wanting to travel through the USA, so asking for alternatives is not always because if previous travel trouble.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it may well be true that some people can obtain a transit visa after having been refused a tourist visa, but there are many people who are disqualified from getting any sort of US visa, including transit visas.

Answer (score 6):

The [Wikipedia listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynden_Pindling_International_Airport#Passenger) of destinations served from Nassau airport indicates it is possible to fly there from the following cities outside of the US year-round:

- Canada: Toronto
- Cuba: Havana
- Turks and Caicos Islands: Providenciales
- Haiti: Cap Haitien, Port au Prince
- UK: London
- Jamaica: Kingston
- Trinidad and Tobago: Port of Spain
- Panama: Panama City

There are others which are not year-round too.